# How to turn elements of a list into their negative counterpart if their index mod 4 is greater than 1?

Tags: python, slice

I'm trying to convert a list, say, `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... , n]` into another list `L' = [1, 2, -3, -4, 5, 6, -7, -8, ...., ±n]` in Python.
My question is if there is a shorter/more efficient way of doing that than using a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    if i%4 > 1:
        L[i] *= -1
```

e.g. by slicing.

Comment: list comprehension maybe `L = [-x if i%4 > 1 else x for x in L]`

Comment: shorter, yes. More efficient, no.

Comment: Having the data just be off by one from the indices is perhaps not the clearest example? Took me two extra squizzes before I noticed.

Comment: Your example and code did NOT match each other!  Please confirm and clarify ... if can.

Comment: @DanielHao That's what I thought until I noticed that the index and data are off by one - a bad example.

Comment: @Grismar: I thought it was clearer this way around since 0 = -0. Then again, I could've started at 10, I guess.

Comment: Since three people already fell for it, within 13 minutes of posting, I think that guess should be a certainty :)

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is fairly *efficient*, since it doesn't waste space for a new `L'`, unless you need to preserve the original list of course, in which case your code is wrong.

If you just care about *speed* instead of efficiency, you could start out with a numpy array instead of a list, since you'd be able to come up with an operation that may execute faster than the list operation.

If you care about *shorter*, the comprehension offered by @wkl is the way to go.

```
l_prime = [-x if i%4 > 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(l)]
```

Here's the implementations, timed with `timeit` (standard library):

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np
import itertools, operator


def samuel(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i % 4 > 1:
            l[i] *= -1
    return l


def chai(l):
    return list(map(operator.mul, l, itertools.cycle([1, 1, -1, -1])))


def wkl(l):
    return [-x if i % 4 > 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(l)]


def vladimir(l):
    ar = np.array(l)
    ar[2::4] *= -1
    ar[3::4] *= -1
    return ar.tolist()


# ensure all outcomes are the same
assert samuel(list(range(1000))) == chai(list(range(1000))) == wkl(list(range(1000))) == vladimir(list(range(1000)))

print('samuel: ', timeit(lambda: samuel(list(range(1000))), number=100000))
print('chai: ', timeit(lambda: chai(list(range(1000))), number=100000))
print('wkl: ', timeit(lambda: wkl(list(range(1000))), number=100000))
print('vladimir: ', timeit(lambda: vladimir(list(range(100000))), number=1000))
```

Result:

```
samuel:  6.736065300000519
chai:  3.7625152999999045
wkl:  7.069251500000064
vladimir:  6.424349999997503
```

The numpy solution would be made to be faster, without the list conversions, as stated:

```
def vladimir_a(ar):
    ar[2::4] *= -1
    ar[3::4] *= -1
    return ar.tolist()


ar = np.array(list(range(1000)))
print('vladimir array: ', timeit(lambda: vladimir_a(ar), number=100000))
```

Result:

```
vladimir array:  1.269356699999662
```

(I'm aware `ar` will be modified 100,000 times, but it doesn't affect the performance)

Edit: actually, that's unfair - the ranges were all in the timed section, this would be fair (and not so great)

```
def vladimir_a(ar):
    ar[2::4] *= -1
    ar[3::4] *= -1
    return ar.tolist()


print('vladimir array: ', timeit(lambda: vladimir_a(np.array(range(1000))), number=100000))
```

Result:

```
vladimir array:  6.5144264999998995
```

So you may need to do some timing in your actual use case to find what's fastest there. Constructing the same array 100000 times (or the same list) clearly isn't what you're doing, and one would expect you are operating on a large dataset for speed to even be a consideration.

Comment: I would suggest for the function to take `n` as an argument, use `np.arange` to create an array, modify it, and return `ar`. This way, all the overhead of converting between numpy arrays and lists is removed.

Comment: On my machine this function runs around 70 times faster than the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3, you can use `itertools`'s `cycle` to repeat an iterable over and over again, and then use `map` to combine two iterables with some function:

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> list(map(operator.mul, range(10), itertools.cycle([1, 1, -1, -1])))
[0, 1, -2, -3, 4, 5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
>>> list(map(operator.mul, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19], itertools.cycle([1, 1, -1, -1])))
[2, 3, -5, -7, 11, 13, -17, -19]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comparison of various methods:

```
import time
import numpy as np

n = int(1e7)

s1 = time.time()
L1 = list(range(1, n))
for i in range(len(L1)):
    if i % 4 > 1:
        L1[i] *= -1
e1 = time.time()

s2 = time.time()
L2 = list(range(1, n))
L2 = np.array(L2)
L2[np.arange(n - 1) % 4 > 1] *= -1
L2 = L2.tolist()
e2 = time.time()

s3 = time.time()
L3 = list(range(1, n))
L3 = np.array(L3)
k = (n - 1) // 4
pat = [False, False, True, True]
idx = np.concatenate((np.tile(pat, k), pat[:n - k * 4 - 1])).astype(bool)
L3[idx] *= -1
L3 = L3.tolist()
e3 = time.time()

s4 = time.time()
L4 = list(range(1, n))
L4 = np.array(L4)
L4[2::4] *= -1
L4[3::4] *= -1
L4 = L4.tolist()
e4 = time.time()

assert all(np.array(L1) == np.array(L2))
assert all(np.array(L1) == np.array(L3))
assert all(np.array(L1) == np.array(L4))

print(f'time1: {e1 - s1:.2f}s, time2: {e2 - s2:.2f}s, time3: {e3 - s3:.2f}s, time4: {e4 - s4:.2f}s')
```

prints

```
time1: 3.76s, time2: 1.72s, time3: 1.58s, time4: 1.52s
```

Comment: Shoutout to @Vladimir Fokow's slicing method

Comment: Timing them is a good idea, given the question's focus on speed and efficiency, but you introduce some overhead, and timing using `time.time()` is not overly reliable - have a look at the answer I gave on how to use the very reliable and fit-for-purpose `timeit` Python module

Comment: @Grismar thanks for the tip. What's the overhead though?

Comment: The same as in my version of Vladimir's solution, which is unfair to the numpy solution, there's no need for list conversions. (although you can argue it makes sense to show the difference, which I included as well)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Grismar’s answer, numpy arrays can be dramatically faster than iteration because they do operations in parallel (even on CPUs).

Here is how to solve your problem using numpy arrays (with slicing):

```py
import numpy as np

# If you already have a list `L`:
ar = np.array(L)

# But it’s faster to use numpy to 
# generate the array of numbers 
# (here: integers from 1 to n):
n = 15
ar = np.arange(1, n + 1)

ar[2::4] *= -1
ar[3::4] *= -1

# You can convert a numpy array into a list. 
# Note that this step may not be necessary 
# at all, because numpy arrays can be
# used where you would use lists. 
# But for completeness, here is how to do it:
L_prime = ar.tolist()
```

---

A function you can use:

```py
def make_array(n):
    ar = np.arange(1, n + 1)
    ar[2::4] *= -1
    ar[3::4] *= -1
    return ar
```